# Create Dynamic DB connection in yii after fill form?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am new to use YII. In YII I need to create db connection when user fill form for example in a form I require these fields from user for db connection:

```
Host:   Port:    Username:    Password:    Dababase name:
```

When user click on connect with database. Then I need to create connection with database and load the Entered database tables.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read the guides on [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) in order to better understand your question and provide you with even better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the input for create dinamically the connection

```
$connection = new \yii\db\Connection([
   'dsn' => $dsn,
   'username' => $username,
   'password' => $password,
]);
```

see  this guide for more http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-connection.html  and http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-databases.html

Comment: Will you please guide me a bit more. Where i use this code. In main.php or in my an other file. Thanks for your  effort

Comment: this is for an use in line  ..alias  when  you get the values from your form and want connect to a specific server/database ...   the $connection is the var that allow you all the sql command  or activeRecord or activeQuery you need